# I used load_cnosdb to write data and found that the write speed was slowly decreasing

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

I used load_cnosdb to write data and found that the write speed was slowly decreasing

I've recorded the average speed of the first ten times and the average speed of the last ten times：

```
# top 10
1701921216,4854777.31,4.855507E+07,4854777.31,613707.71,6.138000E+06,613707.71
1701921226,4637445.44,9.492839E+07,4746120.88,586314.37,1.200100E+07,600012.24
1701921236,4219973.69,1.371281E+08,4570746.00,533500.72,1.733600E+07,577842.68
1701921246,4446020.35,1.815895E+08,4539564.90,562084.17,2.295700E+07,573903.09
1701921256,4428900.78,2.258753E+08,4517434.05,559941.14,2.855600E+07,571110.95
1701921266,4602797.08,2.719041E+08,4531661.25,581889.34,3.437500E+07,572907.35
1701921276,4089263.81,3.127996E+08,4468458.64,516963.18,3.954500E+07,564914.95
1701921286,4498494.46,3.577846E+08,4472213.04,568700.32,4.523200E+07,565388.11
1701921296,4063430.00,3.984172E+08,4426795.21,513721.10,5.036900E+07,559647.65
1701921306,3837351.89,4.367890E+08,4367854.03,485122.02,5.522000E+07,552195.49
1701921316,4324021.65,4.800334E+08,4363868.94,546646.40,6.068700E+07,551690.98
......
# last 10
1701922956,4020166.69,6.772497E+09,3869994.71,508205.27,8.561960E+08,489254.41
1701922966,4037536.80,6.812869E+09,3870946.58,510441.47,8.613000E+08,489374.78
1701922976,3192851.83,6.844801E+09,3867115.17,403661.92,8.653370E+08,488890.48
1701922986,3768008.38,6.882477E+09,3866558.45,476344.52,8.701000E+08,488820.01
1701922996,3071433.09,6.913192E+09,3862116.36,388296.18,8.739830E+08,488258.42
1701923006,3463058.52,6.947823E+09,3859899.31,437787.44,8.783610E+08,487978.01
1701923016,4411538.39,6.991937E+09,3862946.96,557715.35,8.839380E+08,488363.29
1701923026,4428839.65,7.036226E+09,3866056.25,559901.92,8.895370E+08,488756.36
1701923036,2540858.68,7.061634E+09,3858814.68,321197.72,8.927490E+08,487840.73
1701923046,4472285.57,7.106359E+09,3862148.90,565375.89,8.984030E+08,488262.14
```

I'm writing 200 gigabytes of line protocol data here, the cmd as follow:

```
cat cnodb-iot-seed-123-scale-100-2016.gz|gunzip|load_cnosdb --batch-size 15000 --workers 500 --db-name benchmark  --urls http://127.0.0.1:8902
```

I am deploy mode was 3meta+2querytskv, which is office [repo](https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb) [run_cluster.sh](https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/blob/main/run_cluster.sh)

the monitor as follow:

[image]